# App crashes when tapping a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

When I launch my app, tap on a cell in my RootViewController  (`AufnahmeIstTableViewController`), it opens up my DetailViewController (`AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController`).When I then tap on cell, it should open a third ViewController (`AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController`). My app works like in this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99Ssk1-HUq4

But in my label, no text is displayed. What is the error? What do I have to change?

Here are all my files:

Here is my AufnahmeIstTableViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AufnahmeIstTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *categoryArray;
@end
```

Here's my AufnahmeIstTableViewController.m file:

```
#import "AufnahmeIstTableViewController.h"
#import "AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.h"

@interface AufnahmeIstTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation AufnahmeIstTableViewController
@synthesize categoryArray;


-(NSMutableArray *)categoryArray
{
    if (!categoryArray)

    {
        categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return categoryArray;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Gesetze"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Verordnungen"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Technische Regeln"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Berufsgenossenschaft"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Management"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Personal"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Vertrieb"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Kunden"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Lieferanten"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Arbeitsumgebung"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Produktion"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Produkte"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Messmittel"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Informationssicherheit"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Rechnungswesen"];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:@"Dritte"];

    [self setTitle:@"Ist-Aufnahme"];


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.categoryArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.categoryArray [indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController *categories = [[AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController alloc]init];

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Gesetze"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 0;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Verordnungen"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 1;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Technische Regeln"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 2;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Berufsgenossenschaft"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 3;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Management"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 4;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Personal"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 5;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Vertrieb"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 6;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Kunden"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 7;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Lieferanten"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 8;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Arbeitsumgebung"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 9;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Produktion"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 10;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Produkte"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 11;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Messmittel"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 12;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Informationssicherheit"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 13;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Rechnungswesen"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 14;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Dritte"])
        categories.istAufnahmeInt = 15;


    [categories setTitle:[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:categories animated:YES];
     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
#pragma mark - Navigation
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailView"])
{
    AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController *controller = (AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Gesetze"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 0;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Verordnungen"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 1;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Technische Regeln"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 2;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Berufsgenossenschaft"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 3;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Management"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 4;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Personal"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 5;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Vertrieb"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 6;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Kunden"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 7;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Lieferanten"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 8;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Arbeitsumgebung"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 9;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Produktion"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 10;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Produkte"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 11;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Messmittel"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 12;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Informationssicherheit"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 13;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Rechnungswesen"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 14;

    if ([[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row] isEqual:@"Dritte"])
        controller.istAufnahmeInt = 15;

    [controller setTitle:[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row]];
}
}


@end
```

Here's my AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AufnahmeIstTableViewController.h"
#import "AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController.h"

@interface AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *gesetzeArray;
    NSMutableArray *verordnungenArray;
    NSMutableArray *technischeregelnArray;
    NSMutableArray *berufsgenossenschaftArray;
    NSMutableArray *managementArray;
    NSMutableArray *personalArray;
    NSMutableArray *vertriebArray;
    NSMutableArray *kundenArray;
    NSMutableArray *lieferantenArray;
    NSMutableArray *arbeitsumgebungArray;
    NSMutableArray *produktionArray;
    NSMutableArray *produkteArray;
    NSMutableArray *messmittelArray;
    NSMutableArray *informationssicherheitArray;
    NSMutableArray *rechnungswesenArray;
    NSMutableArray *dritteArray;


}
@property int istAufnahmeInt;
@property AufnahmeIstTableViewController *categories;

-(void)makeData;


@end
```

And here's my AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.m file:

```
#import "AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.h"
#import "AufnahmeIstTableViewController.h"
#import "AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController.h"

@interface AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController
@synthesize istAufnahmeInt;
@synthesize categories;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    [self makeData];

}
-(void)makeData
{
    gesetzeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    verordnungenArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    technischeregelnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    berufsgenossenschaftArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    managementArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    personalArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    vertriebArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    kundenArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    lieferantenArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arbeitsumgebungArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    produktionArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    produkteArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    messmittelArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    informationssicherheitArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    rechnungswesenArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    dritteArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //Gesetze
        [gesetzeArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];

    //Verordnungen
        [verordnungenArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Verordnung zur arbeitsmedizinischen Vorsorge – ArbMedVV",@"name",@"Verordnung zur arbeitsmedizinischen Vorsorge – ArbMedVV wurde gedrückt",@"description", nil]];

    //Technische Regeln
        [technischeregelnArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Technische Regeln",@"name",@"Technische Regeln wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Berufsgenossenschaft
        [berufsgenossenschaftArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Berufsgenossenschaft",@"name",@"Berufsgenossenschaft wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Management
        [managementArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Personal
        [personalArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Vertrieb
        [vertriebArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Kunden
        [kundenArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Lieferanten
        [lieferantenArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Arbeitsumgebung
        [arbeitsumgebungArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Produktion
        [produktionArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Produkte
        [produkteArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Messmittel
        [messmittelArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Informationssicherheit
        [informationssicherheitArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Rechnungswesen
        [rechnungswesenArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
    //Dritte
        [dritteArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz",@"name",@"Bundesdatenschutzgesetz wurde gedrückt", @"description", nil]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 0)
    {
        return [gesetzeArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 1)
    {
        return [verordnungenArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 2)
    {
        return [technischeregelnArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 3)
    {
        return [berufsgenossenschaftArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 4)
    {
        return [managementArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 5)
    {
        return [personalArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 6)
    {
        return [vertriebArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 7)
    {
        return [kundenArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 8)
    {
        return [lieferantenArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 9)
    {
        return [arbeitsumgebungArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 10)
    {
        return [produktionArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 11)
    {
        return [produkteArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 12)
    {
        return [messmittelArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 13)
    {
        return [informationssicherheitArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 14)
    {
        return [rechnungswesenArray count];
    }
    if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 15)
    {
        return [dritteArray count];
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"DetailCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 0) cell.textLabel.text = [[gesetzeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 1) cell.textLabel.text = [[verordnungenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name" ];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 2) cell.textLabel.text = [[technischeregelnArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 3) cell.textLabel.text = [[berufsgenossenschaftArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 4) cell.textLabel.text = [[managementArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 5) cell.textLabel.text = [[personalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 6) cell.textLabel.text = [[vertriebArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 7) cell.textLabel.text = [[kundenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 8) cell.textLabel.text = [[lieferantenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 9) cell.textLabel.text = [[arbeitsumgebungArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 10) cell.textLabel.text = [[produktionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 11) cell.textLabel.text = [[produkteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 12) cell.textLabel.text = [[messmittelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 13) cell.textLabel.text = [[informationssicherheitArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 14) cell.textLabel.text = [[rechnungswesenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
                if (self.istAufnahmeInt == 15) cell.textLabel.text = [[dritteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];


    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController *aufnahmeistDetail =[[AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController"  bundle:nil];

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 0)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[gesetzeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[gesetzeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 1)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[verordnungenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[verordnungenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 2)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[technischeregelnArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[technischeregelnArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 3)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[berufsgenossenschaftArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[berufsgenossenschaftArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 4)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[managementArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[managementArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 5)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[personalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[personalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 6)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[vertriebArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[vertriebArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 7)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[kundenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[kundenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 8)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[lieferantenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[lieferantenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 9)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[arbeitsumgebungArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[arbeitsumgebungArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 10)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[produktionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[produktionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 11)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[produkteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[produkteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 12)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[messmittelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[messmittelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 13)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[informationssicherheitArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[informationssicherheitArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 14)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[rechnungswesenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[rechnungswesenArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (istAufnahmeInt == 15)
    {
        aufnahmeistDetail.titelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[dritteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
        aufnahmeistDetail.title = [[dritteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }


}
@end
```

Here's my AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.h"
@interface AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController : UIViewController

{
    IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
    NSString *titelString;
    NSString *textString;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *titelString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *textString;


@end
```

And finally, here's my AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.m file:

```
#import "AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController.h"
#import "AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController.h"

@interface AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController
@synthesize textString;
@synthesize titelString;

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    titleLabel.text = titelString;
    textLabel.text = textString;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: The problem is probably in IB, not in this code dump. You have something in IB called "detailtextLabel" that doesn't exist in AufnahmeISTDetailTableViewController. Find it and delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the way you are doing this is not very well.
You often repeat almost the same code -> [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

From what I can tell by looking slightly through your code, at the moment you do not need all those if-cases because you could just set `categories.istAufnahmeInt = indexPath.row` it would be the same…

Concerning your error, everything you need to know to identify the error is already within your error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController 0x12c65fdd0 setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: **this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key detailtextLabel.'**

It tells you that your `AufnahmeIstDetailDetailViewController` either does **not** have a label called `detailtextLabel` **or** it's not connected to your view -> check your storyboard / xib

Comment: OK, I found it and fixed it, but now I don't get any text where my label is. Do you know what the error could be here?

Answer (score 0):

Check the viewcontroller on the storyboard. Key-Value coding errors are typically here. The log output says "detailtextLabel" is the problem. My guess is there is a reference on the storyboard to a property that either no longer exists, or you renamed.

Answer (score 0):

detailtextLabel is in your error message but I don't see it in your code.  Try to find it in your project